# Matlab, how to convert image array to integer array?

Tags: image, matlab

I want to get the values of two gray scale images and apply some operations between them but if the result is below 0 of over 255 I get 0 or 255 respectively.

How can I convert this values to integers so I go below 0 or over 255?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `uint8` which only supports that range. To allow negative values you have to use a signed integer like `int16` or `int32`. For a conversion without rescaling use `int16`, for a conversion with rescaling use `im2int16`